# What is the http://go2.wordpress.com/ redirect?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, redirect

Hi I see a [wordpress.co](http://openunionism.wordpress.com/)m blog and on the latest post there is a redirect for the external links via "http://go2.wordpress.com/" redirect. This redirect is obfuscated - on hovering the link it displays a "http://google.com/url?..." redirect instead.

What is this and why is it suddenly on this post and not others?

Also, I see the redirect type is a 302 - surely this is harmful in terms of SEO for the destination links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be generated by API for affiliate service.

See this topic [Link redirection through go2.wordpress.com](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/link-redirection-through-go2wordpresscom):

> The redirection is for a skimlinks ad
>   service we are running.

Comment: any idea on the SEO implications for target destinations?

Comment: @rutherford I am no expert on that. I assume extra redirects are unlikely to be beneficial, the more stuff there is the more crawler needs to make sense of.